# Python get full path for files in folder passed as argument

Tags: python, filepath, os.path

My goal is to be able to parse through a folder containing multiples images and get the absolute path for them so I can load them into OpenCV.

A single folder is passed in containing an unknown number of images.

```
#FilePass.py

import os
import cv2
import argparse
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-1", "--first", required=True)
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
imagesToStitch = os.listdir(args["first"])
for image in imagesToStitch:
    print os.path.abspath(image)
```

This is the command to execute with the file path to the folder being used.

```
# python FilePass.py --first C:\Users\cradford\Documents\Research\ImagesToPass\Pass1
```

The images contained are and their corresponding full file path are:

```
_001.jpg # "C:\Users\cradford\Documents\Research\ImagesToPass\Pass1"
_002.jpg # "C:\Users\cradford\Documents\Research\ImagesToPass\Pass1"
```

Desired output:

```
C:\Users\cradford\Documents\Research\ImagesToPass\Pass1\_001.jpg
C:\Users\cradford\Documents\Research\ImagesToPass\Pass1\_002.jpg
```

Output with code used:

```
C:\Users\cradford\Documents\Research\OpenCV Practice Files\_001.jpg
C:\Users\cradford\Documents\Research\OpenCV Practice Files\_002.jpg
```

I am pretty sure the discrepancy where the result reads "OpenCV Practice Files" is because it is looking at the abs.path of "image" in my for loop and the code file is saved in "OpenCV Practice Files".
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please, don't spam tags. There's nothing relevant to OpenCV in this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll likely want to use `os.path.join`

```
for image in imagesToStitch:
    print os.path.join(args["first"], image)
```

Comment: `os.path.join()` doesn't normalize, nor does it convert relative paths to absolute. He might have wanted `os.path.abspath(os.path.join(args["first"], image))`.

Comment: You are my hero. I would up vote but only at 6 rep lol. Thanks for your help

Comment: Hey Rob thanks that exactly what I came up with as well and ended up doing and it worked great.